# C++ Multi-dimensional Array Comma Index Address

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

In playing around with multi-dimensional arrays, I found that if I used a comma to separate the indices, it would return to me the address of the element in the array, disregarding the first comma. This is shown by the following example:

```cpp
int arr[3][3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        // Output arr[,] test
        cout << "arr[" << i << "," << j << "]: " << arr[i,j] << endl;
    }
}
cout << "\n--------------\n" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        // Output arr[][] test
        cout << "arr[" << i << "][" << j << "]: " << &arr[i][j] << endl;
    }
}
```

This gives the output:

```
arr[0,0]: 0x28feec
arr[0,1]: 0x28fef8
arr[0,2]: 0x28ff04
arr[1,0]: 0x28feec
arr[1,1]: 0x28fef8
arr[1,2]: 0x28ff04
arr[2,0]: 0x28feec
arr[2,1]: 0x28fef8
arr[2,2]: 0x28ff04

--------------

arr[0][0]: 0x28feec
arr[0][1]: 0x28fef0
arr[0][2]: 0x28fef4
arr[1][0]: 0x28fef8
arr[1][1]: 0x28fefc
arr[1][2]: 0x28ff00
arr[2][0]: 0x28ff04
arr[2][1]: 0x28ff08
arr[2][2]: 0x28ff0c
```

As you can see, the address values at `[0,0]`/`[0][0]`, `[0,1]`/`[1][0]`, and `[0,2]`/`[2][0]` match up. They also match wherever the second one in the `[n,n]` pair matches with the first number in the `[n][n]` pair.

I found that this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) about comma operators in C++ agrees with this skipping:

> In Pascal, multidimensional arrays are indexed using commas, e.g. `A[i, j]`. In C, however, `A[i, j]` is equivalent to `A[j]`, since the value of `i` is discarded. The correct way to index multidimensional arrays in C is with a construction like `A[i][j]`.

The only question I have is: **why does it return an address?** The Wikipedia article seems to disagree that it should return an address, because it says that it is "equivalent to `A[j]`".

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers, so when you have an array `myArray[i][j]` by indexing only once: `myArray[i]` you are getting a pointer to an array of size `j`. This is why you are getting a pointer.

Comment: Compilers generally warn about this. Make sure the warning options are set.

Comment: "The Wikipedia article seems to disagree that it should return an address..." - it doesn't return an address. It evaluates to `int (&)[3]`; a reference to an array of three `int`. How you're *using* it in your output expression cause a conversion to `int *`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are addressing a multi-dimensional array, the indices separated by comma `arr[i,j]` , the comma behaves like a [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator).

A comma operator is a binary operator which evaluates all the comma separated expressions completing its side effects and discards it until the last expression in the list. So effectively, it ignored all but the last index in your particular case which is `j`
`arr[j]`.

As the type of `arr[j]` is nothing more than int arr[3], which decays to a pointer `int *`, so printing the value of a pointer displays the address.

---

> To expand on this, [ostream
>   operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/)
>   does not have an overload which can accept a type `Ty[]`, the closest
>   it accepts is `Ty*`,
>
> ```
> ostream& operator<< (void* val);
> ```
>
> so that effectively means, `Ty[]` decays to `Ty*` which is then downcasted to `void *` and calls
>   `ostream& operator<< (void* val)`, which prints the address of the pointer

---

> The Wikipedia article seems to disagree that it should return an
>   address, because it says that it is "equivalent to A[j]". I will very
>   much appreciate an answer to this.

To make this simple, what do you expect the program to print in the following case?

```
int arr[3];
std::cout << arr << std::endl;
```

Comment: So, because I was using multi-dimensional arrays, it is getting `arr[i]`, which would return an address similarly to how a normal array, `arr` would return an address. Good answer!